# Выборочное слияние веток

Tags: git

Есть ветка master, есть еще две ветки для продакшена, пусть будут prod1 и prod2. Вот разрабытываю я новый функционал. Сделал ветку от мастера feature1, сделал фичу, оттестировал, влил в мастер, сделал таким же образом еще пару фич. Т.о. в мастере у меня оказалось три новых фичи. Подошло время релиза. Выкладывание в продакшен происходит путем git pull нужной ветки. Для продакшена1 - это prod1, для второго prod2.
В первый продакшен нужно выложить все три фичи, а во второй только первую и третью (а вторую фичу когда-нибудь потом, или может вообще никогда). В первом случае я могу просто влить мастер в ветку prod1, а вот что делать во втором даже как-то не знаю.

Или вообще может кто-то подскажет, как правильнее строить систему деплоймента в этом случае.

Comment: Неплохие примеры работы с git: http://kb.etersoft.ru/Работа_с_git

Answer (score 3):

- При правильной работе с `master branch` у вас, вообще говоря, не должно возникать проблем с релизными бранчами. Корректный `workflow` при работе с `master` допускает только нижеследующие типы `commit'ов:`

> - `Merge` некоторой `feature branch,` которая прошла `peer review` и готова к интеграции в проект. `[1]`
> - Рефакторинг имеющегося кода, причем классический рефакторинг по Фаулеру - *не изменяющий поведения продукта.* `[2]`
> - Обоснованное исправление какой-либо незначительной проблемы в поведении программы, которое укладывается в один `commit`. Например, изменение отображаемого текста в случае ошибки. `[3]`

- Если все условия, описанные выше, выполняются, то релиз обычно осуществляется следующим образом:

> - В произвольный момент из `master` создается так называемая `polishing branch` (`release branch`), в которой, собственно говоря, осуществляется подготовка к релизу. Эта самая подготовка обычно включает в себя добавление финальной документации, `asset'ов` и выбор `features`, которые должны быть включены в релиз.
> - В зависимости от того, насколько старым является базовый `commit` для `release branch`, необходимо на основании определенного желаемого набора фичей сделать [`cherry-pick`](http://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-cherry-pick.html) для коммитов, в которых реализованы данные фичи, либо, наоборот, сделать [`revert`](http://schacon.github.com/git/git-revert.html) для фичей, который не вносятся в релиз. **Естественно, что данные операции можно считать атомарными с точностью до разрешения конфликтов.**
> - Лично мне больше нравится второй вариант, поскольку в таком случае для ветки получается *более явная история изменений,* а также приходится меньше думать о `cherry-picking'е` коммитов, которые попадают под категорию `[3].`

- Далее, в некоторый момент ветка доходит до финального релизного состояния, которое можно пометить соответствующим `tag'ом`, однако ничто не мешает продолжить работу с ней дальше:

> - Если в какой-то момент времени в продукте обнаруживаются критические недоработки, то их исправления можно [`backport'ить`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Backporting) в старые релизные ветки путем того же самого `cherry-pick` и обновления соответствующего `tag`.
> - Если получается так, что во время работы части команды над `release branch` в `master` оказывается реинтегрирована новая фича, которую *"неплохо бы включить в релиз"*, то ничто не мешает выполнить `git cherry-pick` для соответствующего `commit'a`, тем самым добавив ее в релиз.

- Подробнее про описанный сценарий - см. [**Version Control By Example.**](http://www.amazon.com/Version-Control-Example-Eric-Sink/dp/0983507902)

Answer (score 0):

Я думаю, вам нужно [`git-cherry-pick`](http://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-cherry-pick.html)

> Given one or more existing commits, apply the change each one introduces, recording a new commit for each. This requires your working tree to be clean (no modifications from the HEAD commit).